# SAP ABAP - Field Symbol Has not yet been assigned

Tags: abap, alv

I am trying to use table from another report program as in the following:

```
REPORT  ZSAM3.

 TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_report,
          rec_acc TYPE skont,
          vendor TYPE LFA1-LIFNR,
          jan_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jan_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          feb_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          feb_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          mar_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          mar_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          apr_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          apr_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          may_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          may_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jun_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jun_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jul_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jul_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          aug_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          aug_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          sep_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          sep_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          oct_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          oct_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          nov_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          nov_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          dec_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          dec_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          acc_bal_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          acc_bal_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
        END OF ty_report,
        tt_report TYPE TABLE OF ty_report.

DATA:  lt_report TYPE tt_report,
       lv_ukurs type tcurr-ukurs,
       Tcurr1 type tcurr,
       fieldname(4) type c,
       fnamedebit(20) type c,
       fnamecredit(20) type c.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_rep> LIKE LINE OF lt_report.


 select single ukurs from tcurr
        into lv_ukurs
        where fcurr = 'EUR'
        and   tcurr = 'AUD'. "<- your  local currency

DATA lr_pay_data              TYPE REF TO data.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lt_pay_data>   TYPE ANY TABLE,
               <pos_data> type any.

  cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>set(
    EXPORTING display  = abap_false
              metadata = abap_false
              structure = ''
              data     = abap_true ).

SUBMIT RFKSLD00 via SELECTION-SCREEN and return.


TRY.
    ASSIGN lr_pay_data->* TO <lt_pay_data>.
>>> cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>get_data(
      IMPORTING t_data = <lt_pay_data> ).
  CATCH cx_salv_bs_sc_runtime_info.
    MESSAGE `Unable to retrieve ALV data` TYPE 'E'.
ENDTRY.

LOOP AT <lt_pay_data> ASSIGNING <pos_data>.

 APPEND INITIAL LINE to lt_report ASSIGNING <fs_rep>.
 MOVE-CORRESPONDING <pos_data> TO <fs_rep>.

WRITE: / <pos_data>.

ENDLOOP.

Write: 'Program End!'.
```

I am getting the following runtime error:

> you attenpted to access an anassigned field symbol (data segment 12)

Maybe (as suggested by arrows in the code) that <'lt_pay_data'> has not been initialized or assigned but I do not know how assign any table type variable.

Comment: Why are you not using inline declaration for field symbols? E.g Loop at internal_table assigning Field-Symbols(. <fs_it> )

Answer (score -2):

This could be what's going on in your program:

```
PROGRAM zref.

DATA          lr_pay_data   TYPE REF TO data.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <lt_pay_data> TYPE ANY TABLE.
```

*From F1 on ASSIGN: " If the reference variable dref does not reference a data object, the assignment is not performed and sy-subrc is set to 4 "*

```
ASSIGN lr_pay_data->* TO <lt_pay_data>.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  MESSAGE 'You need to CREATE DATA for your REF TO variable before dereferencing it' TYPE 'S'.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: <lt_pay_data> should take on the output from cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>get_data but maybe it needs to be initialized first. you know how?